# An error occured. Reason:0004-Certificate found in Signature or KeyDescriptor under element "EntityDescriptor" is not trusted

Tags: spring-security, ssl-certificate, single-sign-on, spring-saml

An error occured. Reason:0004-Certificate found in Signature or KeyDescriptor under element "EntityDescriptor" is not trusted.

I am using Spring security SAML for implementing SSO and testing it against SSOCircle. but whenever I am uploading generated metadata. I am getting the above error.

When I am removing the certificates from the SP metadata it is working fine. But How should I work with the certificates or make those certificates trusted for SSO circle to work with.

The certificates I am working with are issues by trusted CA.

Comment: Can you provide any samples of how you're setting everything up and executing it?

Answer (score 1):

Is your SP metadata signed? If yes, please remove the signature element in the metadata. 
Please note: You do not need to remove the signing certificates from the metadata. The signing certificate is still used to verify the signature of the requests.